# Linux Server Directory Tree Structure

Tags: linux

I have a issue with my client's linux server.
Can some body knows me what is the maximum limit of directory structure size on linux server?

I am not able to create more than 8000 directory in my websites root's 1 directory.

Comment: Whatever you're doing, I think you should try something else.

Comment: It depends on the filesystem - you don't say which you are using. There's also a limit on the number of inodes on the whole filesystem (df -i) as well as the physical capacity. "in my websites root's 1 directory" - we don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1):

for ext3 it is 32000 directories per inode.

Comment: … also subject to other limitations as described in @symcbean's comment on the original answer.